# What is the best IPFS provider for Cardano NFT that uses CidV0?

Tags: cardano-cli, nft, ipfs

I am relatively new to the IPFS and NFT world. I am interested in finding the best IPFS provider for storing NFT files that are later used for minting a Cardano NFT. Currently, I am using Nft.Storage, which seems to be the complete leader in the IPFS and NFT world, but I have a problem that Nft.Storage exclusively works with CidV1 while Cardano has a metadata limitation that restricts me to CidV0.

Also, when I convert CidV1 to CidV0, I am unable to find the uploaded file in the IPFS explorer. I don't know if I need to map something somewhere, not sure how gateway resolve file if cidv1 is converted to cidv0?

So what is the best IPFS provider for Cardano that support CidV0, or do you know how IPFS gateway can resolved converted CidV0?

Answer (score 1):

[Blockfrost.io](https://blockfrost.io/) is probably the most popular within the Cardano ecosystem right now. (*I'm from the BF team*).

If you mint using [NMKR](https://www.nmkr.io/), they are pinning your files too.

Also, [nftcdn.io](https://nftcdn.io) is launching their service very soon.